# Android app too heavy

Tags: android

can we delete android.jar from the signed apk file as explained by the author here -

http://michaelpardo.com/2010/04/one-way-to-reduce-your-apk-file-size/

I want to be sure before trying. I have some 40 png files making my app very heavy. I also have some 20 music files which will make it even heavier. Any suggestion for compressing png and .mp3 files?

Answer (score 2):

`android.jar` is not in your signed APK file. `android.jar` is a compile-time library. The equivalent Java classes already exist on devices.

Comment: Agreed, `android.jar` is stripped down version of `framework.jar` file that you can find on device, usually at `/system/framework/` folder. The `android.jar` is only used for compile time verification of source code, while 'framework.jar' is the library that has actual code in it. So, basically. `android.jar` will never be included in `.apk` file.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting android.jar can be a risk.
For mp3 try converting them back using ImToo 3GP video convertor using lower rate.
For png try some image compressor, such as [Pngcrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush).

This way you can reduce the size along with the safe side in hand.

:)